# Prove longest path shares two points

Tags: graphs

If there are two longest paths in a connected graph with path lengths of 79 (going through 80 vertices each). How can I prove that they share more than 1 vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they only cross at a single vertex $v$, consider the distance from that $v$ to the four path ends. Since the lengths are odd, $v$ can not be in the exact middle of the paths. But then, are the paths really the longest ones?